# Hard Disk handling using 32-bit system call in assembly language

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, dos, masm

friends, I need help regarding Harddisk handling using 32-bit system call. I am new to assembly language and I am using MASM assembler. I have tried some example codes but they are in 16-bit mode, and also i gives me error, while compling. I want to write in 32-bit. and i also read in a book that 32-bit is complicated, Is there any another procedure for 32-bit system call.

Example Code!

```
; This program calls INT 21h Function 7303h, to get free space information
; on a FAT-type drive volume. It displays both the volume size and free space.
; Runs under Windows 95/98/Me, but not under Windows NT/2000/XP.
; Last update: 12/11/01

INCLUDE Irvine16.inc

.data

buffer ExtGetDskFreSpcStruc <>
driveName BYTE "C:\",0
str1 BYTE "Volume size (KB): ",0
str2 BYTE "Free space (KB):  ",0
str3 BYTE "Function call failed.",0dh,0ah,0

.code
main PROC
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax

    mov  buffer.Level,0     ; must be zero
    mov  di, OFFSET buffer      ; ES:DI points to buffer
    mov  cx, SIZEOF buffer      ; buffer size
    mov  dx, OFFSET DriveName   ; ptr to drive name
    mov  ax, 7303h          ; Get disk free space
    int  21h
    jc   error          ; Failed if CF = 1

    mov  dx,OFFSET str1     ; volume size
    call WriteString
    call CalcVolumeSize
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf

    mov  dx,OFFSET str2     ; free space
    call WriteString
    call CalcVolumeFree
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
    jmp  quit
error:
    mov  dx,OFFSET str3
    call WriteString
quit:
    exit
main ENDP

;-------------------------------------------------------------------
CalcVolumeSize PROC
; Calculate and return the disk volume size, in kilobytes.
; Receives: buffer variable, a ExtGetDskFreSpcStruc structure
; Returns:  EAX = volume size
; Remarks:  (SectorsPerCluster * 512 * TotalClusters) / 1024
;--------------------------------------------------------------------
    mov eax,buffer.SectorsPerCluster
    shl eax,9           ; mult by 512
    mul buffer.TotalClusters
    mov ebx,1024
    div ebx             ; return kilobytes
    ret
CalcVolumeSize ENDP


;-------------------------------------------------------------------
CalcVolumeFree PROC
; Calculate and return the number of available kilobytes on the
;           given volume.
; Receives: buffer variable, a ExtGetDskFreSpcStruc structure
; Returns:  EAX = available space, in kilobytes
; Remarks:  (SectorsPerCluster * 512 * AvailableClusters) / 1024
;--------------------------------------------------------------------
    mov eax,buffer.SectorsPerCluster
    shl eax,9           ; mult by 512
    mul buffer.AvailableClusters
    mov ebx,1024
    div ebx             ; return kilobytes
    ret
CalcVolumeFree ENDP

END main
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What OS are you targeting?

Comment: Is this code one of the 16bit examples you found and already know isn't useful?

Answer (score 3):

Trying to assemble this program...

> also i gives me error

Firstly, it cannot assemble because the struct `ExtGetDskFreSpcStruc` in the line

```
buffer ExtGetDskFreSpcStruc <>
```

is not defined before - not in this file and not in (the only) include file(s), in this case "[Irvine16.inc](http://home.aubg.bg/students/TMG120/irvine/irvine/Examples/Lib16/Irvine16_Library/Irvine16.asm)", which doesn't contain the definition. Therefore all attempted accesses to "buffer.xxx" will throw errors.

Secondly, if you are trying to assemble this program for 32-bit, you are including a 16-bit include file in a 32-bit assembly file. You should use the 32-bit version "Irvine32.inc", because otherwise all indirect addressing like `mov al, [si]`(16-bit) in the subroutines will fail.

Thirdly, you are calling DOS-legacy-interrupts, which are available only in Win95/98/Me, because their kernels are based on DOS. The newer NT kernel in Win2000 and above does not provide them, because it was a different OS architecture/codebase without/with reduced legacy code. The DOS-interrupt(21h) is 16-bit, because DOS was 16-bit. I don't know if there are implemented 32-bit versions of old DOS-interrupts in Win95/98/Me. A quick search yielded no indications of this having been realized. The BIOS interrupts used in "Irvine16.inc" are surely 16-bit and therefore unusable(without very complicated workarounds) in a 32-bit executable probably crashing the program.

> Is there any another procedure for 32-bit system call[?]

Yes. Use the Win32-API, which is available in Win95 till Win8/10(?).
The easiest way to do this would be using the MASM-package by Hutch found at [MOVSD.COM](http://movsd.com/) and then include `kernel32.inc/lib` from it. Then you can call the [GetFreeDiskSpace function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the desired result with a line similar to this:

```
invoke GetFreeDiskSpace, 
  offset driveName, 
  offset buffer.lpSectorsPerCluster,       ; adjust to actual buffer layout names
  offset buffer.lpBytesPerSector,          ; "
  offset buffer.lpNumberOfFreeClusters,    ; "
  offset buffer.lpTotalNumberOfClusters    ; "
```

Comment: 32-bit versions of Windows can still emulate DOS, but only for 16-bit executables.  64-bit versions do not include DOS emulation.

Comment: @Harry Johnston: Yes. What I meant (and wrote) was, that Win95/98/Me are _based_ on DOS and hence do not need to emulate it. 32-bit Windows versions with the NT kernel can emulate it, probably using *Virtual x86 Mode*, which is not available in LongMode(64bit).